# Server doesn't respond in Socket Java programming

Tags: java

This java code program should be read a text from std input, send a message over a socket and get the uppercase version of the text.
I don't know why the server can't receive property the message from the client. Someone can help me with  some basics? I can't debug my mistake.

Server

```
 public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {
    ServerSocket servSocket=new ServerSocket(7000);
    System.out.println("Server up");
   /* while(true)
    {*/
        Socket client=servSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Connessione con "+client.getPort()+" "+client.getInetAddress());
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out= new PrintWriter (client.getOutputStream(),true);
        String testo = in.readLine(); 
        System.out.println("Text Received"+testo);
        testo=testo.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("Answer sent");
        out.println(testo);
        client.close();

//    }
    
}
```

This is the client

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 7000);
        PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("digit a string");
        String txt=scan.next();
        out.println(txt);
        System.out.println("string sent");
        
        String risultato=in.readLine();
        System.out.println("received: "+risultato);
        
        s.close();

    } 
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Try flushing in the client.  After `out.println(txt);` do `out.flush();`.  Similarly flush in the server

Comment: Kind of hard to debug your mistake if you don't tell us what's not working / going wrong / what the error is. Does it hang? When you debug in your IDE, where does it start behaving in ways you don't expect?